# non-principal height one primes of a particular hypersurface

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

I was reading about divisor class groups, and I was wondering the following.

> Let $R=\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z,W]/(XZ-YW)$, and let $x,y,z,w$ be the images of $X,Y,Z,W$ in $R$, respectively. Is there a way to determine all the non-principal height one primes?

I know that four of them are $(x,y)$, $(x,w)$, $(z,y)$ and $(z,w)$.  Are there any others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are in fact many more non-principal height one primes in $R$: e.g. $(xw-y^2, yz-w^2)$ (recall that $(XW-Y^2, YZ-W^2, XZ-YW)$ is the ideal of the twisted cubic, and is a height $2$ prime in $k[X,Y,Z,W]$). One can see this example via algebraic geometry:

$R$ is the coordinate ring of the affine cone over the quadric surface $Q = V(xz-yw) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^3$. Now $Q$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ (under the Segre embedding), so $\text{Cl}(Q) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. Thus any divisor $C$ on $Q$ has a bidegree $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. Furthermore, $C$ has genus $(a-1)(b-1)$ and degree $a+b$, and for any $a, b > 0$ (if $k$ is algebraically closed), there exist irreducible curves $C$ of type $(a,b)$ on $Q$.

An irreducible curve $C$ on $Q$ gives rise to a height $1$ prime in $R$, which is principal iff $C$ is a complete intersection of $Q$ with another hypersurface $D \subseteq \mathbb{P}^3$, say of degree $d$. But a complete intersection of $Q$ with $D$ has genus $\frac{1}{2}(2)(d)(2+d-4) + 1 = (d - 1)^2$ and degree $2d$, so most choices of $(a,b)$ will not give a complete intersection (in fact, this occurs iff $a = b$). The twisted cubic above corresponds to $(a,b) = (1,2)$.

Comment: Surprising.  Thank you!

Comment: In the divisor class group of $R$ (which is $\mathbb Z$) the examples of height one primes given by the OP are equal or opposite. I wonder what's the class of your example of height one prime in terms of $\operatorname{cl}(x,y)$.

Comment: @user26857: There is a natural map $\text{Cl}(Q) \to \text{Cl}(R)$ which in this case is $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, and can vary depending on choices of signs of generators of each copy of $\mathbb{Z}$. The precise description of the map is in Hartshorne (e.g. Ex. II.6.3)

Comment: @zcn Isn't the class of that example $-1$ with respect to $(x,y)$?  I mean, we have $x(xw-y^2, yz-w^2) = (x^2w-xy^2, xyz-xw^2) = (x^2w-xy^2, y^2w - xw^2) = (x,-w)\cdot (xw-y^2)$, so the class of $(xw-y^2, yz-w^2)$ is the same as that of $(x,w)$, which is opposite to that of $(x,y)$.  Right?

Comment: @calearner: Yes, your calculation is completely correct (note though that $(xw - y^2)$ is not a prime ideal in $R$). My previous comment was a bit confused - I was thinking of something else entirely

Comment: (Encouraged by zcn's mistake and my own ignorance) I wonder if it is possible (in a Krull domain whose divisor class group one can suppose to be torsion-free) to have two different height one primes $p$ and $q$ such that $\operatorname{cl}(p)=n\operatorname{cl}(q)$ with $n≠0,±1$.

Comment: @user26857: Here's an explicit counterexample: take the rational quartic curve on $Q$, i.e. $I := (x^2w - y^3, xw^2 - y^2z, w^3 - yz^2)$. This requires $3$ generators and is thus a different class than $(x,y)$ or $(x,w)$. In fact, $\text{cl}(I) = 2 \cdot \text{cl}(x,w)$, since $w^3I = (x,w)^2(w^4 - xz^3)$